# SAXParseException localized

Tags: java, exception

I have service that parse XML and produce report with list of parser errors (`SAXParseException` exactly) using `exception.getMessage()` (`exception.getLocalizedMessage()` return the same) that can be read and understand by humans. How to localize this exception messages in a language other than English ?

Comment: internationalization is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, You're right. Do You know how to do it efficiently ?

Comment: I think the best way would be to have some sort of property file defining all the properties for international languages, and setting default to english (for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution. First need to get `XMLSchemaMessages.properties` from `Apache Xerces`. I downloaded `Xerces-J-src.2.11.0.tar.gz` from http://xerces.apache.org/, unzip and get this file from location: `...\src\org\apache\xerces\impl\msg`.

Now rename this file to **XMLSchemaMessages_pl.properties** or localization You need and place in classpath. I have project in Maven so i put this file into: `src\main\resources\com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg`.

And that's all. Changes to this file will be visible in exception messages.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getLocalizedMessage%28%29), you need to extends `SAXParseException` and override `getLocalizedMessage`, the default implementation returns the same as `getMessage`.

Edit:
You can have seperate property file for each language and in each you can have `code` and `local message`.
When you raise `SAXParseException`, based on the `locale` and some `code`, returns the appropriate `message`.

```
MySAXParseException ex = new MySAXParseException(<code>);
```

Comment: I agree with You, but how to translate all cases for this specific exception `SAXParseException` if You know what i mean...?

Comment: +nice recommendation.