# How to internationalization SAXParseException while parsing XML file?

Tags: java, xml, exception, jaxb, jaxb2

I've got a problem similar to this question: [SAXParseException localized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027681/saxparseexception-localized)

I'm trying to parse a XML file and get a list of parser errors (SAXParseException) in a several languages for example:

`XmlImporter.importFile(params, "en")` should return a list of errors in English, `XmlImporter.importFile(params, "fr")` should return a list of errors in French, `XmlImporter.importFile(params, "pl")` should return a list of errors in Polish language.

Every call of `XmlImporter.importFile(params, "...")` may be with a different locale.

This is my validation method:

```
private void validate(String xmlFilePath, String schemaFilePath) throws Exception {
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(schemaFilePath));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    XmlErrorHandler errorHandler = new XmlErrorHandler();
    validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFilePath))) {
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(stream));
    }
```

XmlErrorHandler:

```
public class XmlErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private List<String> errorsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getErrorsList() {
        return errorsList;
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        errorsList.add(prepareExceptionDescription(exception));
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        errorsList.add(prepareExceptionDescription(exception));
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        errorsList.add(prepareExceptionDescription(exception));
    }

    private String prepareExceptionDescription(SAXParseException exception) {
        return "Error: " +
                "colNumber: " + exception.getColumnNumber() +
                " line number: " + exception.getLineNumber() +
                " message: " + exception.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

I assume, that I need to pass somehow/somewhere java.util.Locale/String to get in exception.getLocalizedMessage() custom message (in en, fr or pl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the default Xerces (Java Parser which is used to convert XML file to Java object) could provide internationalization for given languages:

- XMLSchemaMessages_de.properties XMLSchemaMessages_es.properties
- XMLSchemaMessages_fr.properties XMLSchemaMessages_it.properties
- XMLSchemaMessages_ja.properties XMLSchemaMessages_ko.properties
- XMLSchemaMessages_pt_BR.properties XMLSchemaMessages_sv.properties
- XMLSchemaMessages_zh_CN.properties XMLSchemaMessages_zh_TW.properties

To provide internationalization in other language:

1. Get `XMLSchemaMessages.properties` file from Apache Xerces and rename file to a new file `XMLSchemaMessages_LANG.properties`, where LANG needs to be changed to a new language.
2. Update file's messages to a new language and place this file in a classpath (You can add this file to `src\main\resources\com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg`)
3. Exceptions will be visible in a new language (messages will be taken from `XMLSchemaMessages_LANG.properties` file)