# How to provide internationalization to SAXParseException since JPMS in java 9

Tags: internationalization, java-9, saxparser, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to provide internationalization to SAXParseException messages in Java 11.

I found few solutions e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817751/15272928)  that worked before introduction of JPMS in Java 9. Now (j11) those new bundles e.g. **XMLSchemaMessages_pl.properties** are not visible (loaded but skipped by **ResourceBundle** as they are not in **java.xml** module).

How can I provide internationalization to SAXParser in Java 11?